# How do I store and access values from a deque where deque is being modified by another thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

My program has two threads - first one for receiving data in form of list of dictionaries and 2nd thread for storing the values in a database.

```
buffer = collections.deque(maxlen=10)

def process_ticks(bufferarg):
   while True:
       for i in bufferarg:
            #code to insert data in a database

#this tread receives the data and dumps it into a deque with a specified length (so it can function as a circular buffer)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=socket.connect)

#this threads accesses the deque and processes the data
t2 = threading.Thread(target=process_ticks(buffer))

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

However, when I run the code, I get the "deque is being mutated" error.
Also, how can I make sure that thread runs infinitely, but `process_ticks` doesn't insert same data from deque twice?

Comment: Note that as presented, no thread is ever started: ``process_ticks(buffer)`` already launches the infinite loop, instead of pushing it to the thread. This blocks the main thread. It should say ``t2 = threading.Thread(target=process_ticks, args=(buffer,))`` instead.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks  a lot, mate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generally ill-defined to *iterate* over something while it is being mutated. This is precisely what happens in your case: `t1` mutates the buffer while `t2` iterates over it.

The problem is that iteration assumes strong relations between items; mutation may break this. In specific, a `deque` iterator may hold an element while it is removed, invalidating the reference to the next element.

A simple solution is not to use iteration, but remove elements one at a time:

```
def process_ticks(bufferarg):
    while True:
        try:
            # get and remove one item from the end of the deque
            item = bufferarg.popleft()
        except IndexError:
            # no data in buffer, try again immediately or sleep a little
            continue
        else:
            # do something with item
```

A `deque` is especially suited for this: you can insert and pop at different ends.
This has the added advantage that you can never get the same element twice.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! I've one more question, though, if you don't mind. What would be the most efficient data structure for this process?

Comment: @Yuckfou The ``deque`` is adequate.